# Quickosm and the modeler

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I need to have quickosm run a query via the modeler.

I have found examples on the net, but I cannot modify them for my own use.

I need to download some vectors and create 3 layers.

How do I do that?

First of all I have to make sure that it always retrieves the data from canvas without indicating the area and then I have to create 3 levels, points, lines and areas.

I am attaching the query code so that I better understand what I need.

qgis 3.16
quickosm 1.14.3

````xml
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
    <union>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="railway" v="tram"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="railway" v="rail"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="living_street"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="pedestrian"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>  
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="primary"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="residential"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="secondary"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="service"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="tertiary"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="tertiary_link"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="highway" v="unclassified"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="building"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="building"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vllsE.jpg)
[![error][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gegtP.png
````

Comment: The code is longer, I don't know why he didn't copy it all to me

Comment: Can you add to your post where you are blocked, what you have tried ? If you have a model, you can share it.

Comment: If I perform the procedure from the gui, it creates three perfect layers for me, only to be renamed. If I have it created by the modeler, it doesn't do anything. At first I used the RAW query procedure and that's it. Then seeing examples I implemented other functions. It makes me wrong on the highways and doesn't create anything. I'm up for a picture of the sample found on the net

Comment: You should still share you model, so we can tell you what is wrong. You can share the XML file and the screenshot of the model. (You can click on the small "+" to expand and show your inputs/outpurs names)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16I9N2qr30wKddE0UZMCHX6HvpW8Ngx-a/view?usp=drivesdk. Thisi Is the mod I tried to edit the query with my code but nothing to do. At the moment I'm from a smartphone, I can't access the PC for logistical problems

Comment: I just tried your provided model. It works well, it downloaded a layer with buildings.

Comment: Your model is using `{{geocodeArea:Cambridge}}` but above you are using `{bbox}}`. So the first query will use Cambridge, but the second, you will have to give an extent where to query.